# mysql query WHERE in one table but not the other

Tags: sql, mysql

EDIT:This did it:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT profileid 
FROM profilesrelevation 
WHERE profileid NOT IN (
  SELECT profileid FROM profiles
)
```

I need to get the profileid values that exist in profilesrelevation table but not in profiles table

profiles table have 8107 diffrent "profileid" values while profilesrelevation table has 8380 diffrent "profilesid" values...

profiles.profileid
profilesrelevation.profileid

```
select * from profiles, profilesrelevation 
where profilesrelevation.profileid != profiles.profileid
```

does not work , how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll be wanting to use a set:

```
SELECT DISTINCT profileid 
FROM profilesrelevation 
WHERE profileid NOT IN (
  SELECT profileid FROM profiles
)
```

This selects all rows/columns from `table:profilesrelevation` where the `profileid` of the row isn't also in `table:profiles` :)

Updated: include distinct since it would appear profileid isn't unique in the `profilesrelevation` table.

Comment: the query just keep loading, nothing happends, i have a very strong computer, soemthing must be wrong.

Comment: Thats because of the scale of your data, and likely because you don't have indexes on profileid in either table.  If you can edit the tables try adding indexes.

Comment: ABout the index thing, this is not how i usally do thing, i only use the id table for relating tables, but this is just temporary so i did things diffrently and forgot to add index, if it still takes time, maybe i can do two querys, store in array, compare arrays and then store all data in a third array,

Comment: after adding indexes it went well, but i got to many results, let my try again wait

Comment: the query works well now, but i get duplicate results or more of the same profileid, who do i sort them out.

Comment: the mysql_num_rows is over 9000 when it should be 200 or so, because the profileid exsist on many rows like 1, 3 , 7,7,7,7,7, 50,705,705,606

Comment: i sorted them out, look @ opening post

Answer (score 11):

### Using LEFT JOIN / IS NULL

```
   SELECT pr.*
     FROM PROFILESREVELATION pr
LEFT JOIN PROFILES ON p.profileid = pr.profileid
    WHERE p.profileid IS NULL
```

### Using NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT pr.*
  FROM PROFILESREVELATION pr
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM PROFILES p
                   WHERE p.profileid = pr.profileid)
```

### Using NOT IN

```
SELECT pr.*
  FROM PROFILESREVELATION pr
 WHERE pr.profileid NOT IN (SELECT p.profileid
                              FROM PROFILES p)
```

### Conclusion

The [LEFT JOIN IS NULL is the most efficient on MySQL when the columns compared are not nullable](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/).  If [the columns compared were nullable, NOT IN and NOT EXISTS are more efficient](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/).

Comment: Nicely and succinctly explained.  I would also add that NOT IN starts to degrade performancew-wise as the subquery returns a greater number of records.  Not Exists may be better if the profiles table is very large.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    profilesrelevation.profileid
FROM
    profilesrelevation
    LEFT JOIN profiles ON profilesrelevation.profileid = profiles.profileid
WHERE
    profiles.profileid IS NULL
```

(You may wish to use `SELECT DISTINCT`.)